# Proof of $(x^n)' = nx^{n-1}$ using the natural log and the chain rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

Let's say $y=x^n$ is defined for all real number $x$, including $0$.

I tried out the following proof of the statement $(x^n)' = nx^{n-1}$.

$$y = x^n$$
$$\ln y = n \ln x$$
$$\frac{1}{y} \times y' = n \times \frac{1}{x}$$
$$y' = n \times \frac{y}{x} = n \times \frac{x^n}{x} = nx^{n-1}$$

However on the third line there appears the terms $1/y$ and especially $1/x$ which make the proof invalid for any case where $x = 0$ or $y = 0$ (which always exists in the case of $y=x^n$).

Is there any way to complement this to make proof complete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entire premise is invalid for $x,y\leq 0$ because you take the logarithm. It is impossible to remedy this completely without removing the logarithm from at least part of the procedure.

You can, with some fiddling, fix it for negative $x,y$ by inserting negative signs in strategic places (and you might be expected to do this, or you might not), but for $x=y=0$ there is no salvation if you are to use logarithms. Here you must use other means.

So I wouldn't worry too much about fixing it. Mentioning that this proof has a limited validity will possibly give you some bonus marks, but that's probably the extent of it.